# Can't change colors of Monobehavior events in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine

void Start and void Update are not orange as I want.Same with other Monobehavior methods like `OnTriggerEnter()`, etc.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is recognizing it as a c# class? Visual studio has a tendency to open them as a miscellaneous file. If it has opened it as a miscellaneous file, then close visual studio and find the .sln file in the directory and open it. Then open your c# file.

Comment: It's a theme. Just change your IDE's color scheme or create a new one.

Comment: @hardartcore it's not a theme. The Unity events are highlighted differently. If OP changes their color via theme, all keywords are going to be highlighted in orange. This is probably not what's requested here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the Tools for Unity that come with a Visual Studio installation that has "Game Development with Unity" marked.

To let Unity event messages ([that's what they are officially called](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoBehaviour.html)) not be visualized as keywords, you have to disable the syntax highlighting. This can be done in Visual Studio under Tools > Options... and there under "Tools for Unity" > Code edition > Unity Messages syntax highlighting. Set it to `false`. If this does not work immediately, restart Visual Studio.

---

My advice is to leave it active. These methods are essentially called by the engine, not by you and highlighting them in a different style, makes this more obvious, especially when you use classes that inherit from other types that have methods with the same name.

Comment: Thank you very much!It worked.I've been using Monodevelop for a long time and I love its monokai theme.I  just got used to it. I'm just trying to recreate that  theme in Visual Studio